# Configurar um script PHP para usar o minimo de recursos do sistema?

Tags: php

Tenho um script php que não é pesado, basicamente ele faz uma quantidade gigante de registros em um banco MariaDB. A questão é que esse robô vai demorar algumas horas (Talvez passe de um dia) para rodar completamente, mas isso não é o problema.
A questão é que eu preciso que para este script, seja reservado uma alocação MINIMA de memoria e CPU, para que a execução do mesmo, não prejudique outros pontos mais críticos do sistema.

Alguma dica para isso? Só achei como fazer o contrário.

Comment: Quando ele é executado ele trava o resto por consumir todo o processamento da máquina? Você chegou a analisar qual é a parte do código que é responsável por esse gargalo? Talvez seria mais interessante rever o código desta a partir a fim de remover o gargalo do que limitar o processamento - e talvez fazendo isso diminui inclusive o tempo de execução.

Comment: Não existe gargalo. Eu quero é, na verdade, uma garantia de que, em quanto esse robo estiver em execução, ele não atrapalhe o sistema, eu quero que ele rode com o minimo necessário. VIsto que ele fará um grande numero de acessos ao banco, eu preciso que isso seja feito sem interferir no resto do sistema. Um processo em segundo plano usando o minimo necessário para trabalhar.

Comment: Se o servidor for Apache com php 7  e lhe for conferido manter .htaccess, crie um diretório para esse seu script e dentro do .htacces desse diretório coloque `<IfModule mod_php7.c> php_value memory_limit 32M </IfModule>`, supondo que o limite desejado seja 32Mb.